# Are FBML apps required to upgrade to OAUTH access token by October 1st?

Tags: facebook, oauth, fbml

What is meant by removal of fb_sig ? Is this migration reuqired for Iframe apps using fb_sig and old jssdk or for all apps , including the old FBML canvas apps using and relying on fb_sig post parameters as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Fb_sig params will no longer be sent, so you have to switch to OAuth 2.0 for authentication and also to the signed_request param.

[OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS Migration](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/) states "all Website and Canvas apps must exclusively support OAuth 2.0 (draft 20)" and "all Canvas and Page Tab Apps must use the signed_request parameter".

Also see the "Removing fb_sig" section of [Developer Roadmap Update: Moving to OAuth 2.0 + HTTPS](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/). While that post is from May, I've only seen confirmations since then that fb_sigs will be removed October 1st, and I've seen nothing to the contrary.

Comment: thanks, do you know what will happen to pre load queries ? they use somewhat fb_sig structure..

Comment: Not sure, but I haven't seen any deprecation notices in any blog posts or in the Developer app, so I'd _assume_ they'll still work.